# parsing SQL - allTeradata keywords that select from a table

Tags: sql, parsing, teradata

I am trying to do a quick parse of many sql scripts to determine the source tables and views that are in use.
the idea is to search for "FROM" and take the following word.
I am aware that this may result in subqueries too, but eventually there will be a "FROM" in those as well.

alternative is to join with dbc tables but this would give us a quick first glance.

what keywords should i look for?
JOIN and FROM are the only ones I can currently come up with.
Are there any more keywords?

thank you

Comment: There's always the old schools way of "joining" tables - `from a, b where a.col = b.col...`. If you've got those, you're probably doomed :)

Comment: thanks  - I am fairly hopeful that i will not be doomed, but i will keep it in mind. Thanks for the reminder :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Looking at an existing parser's sources:

I'm looking at [jOOQ](https://www.jooq.org)'s parser's [sources](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/blob/master/jOOQ/src/main/java/org/jooq/impl/ParserImpl.java). It can parse tables in at least these contexts:

**SELECT statement:**

- `FROM` (beware, there's a comma separated list here: `FROM a, b, c` is totally possible)
- `(LEFT, RIGHT, FULL, CROSS) (NATURAL) (INNER, OUTER) JOIN`

Caveats:

- Table references in `FROM` can be derived tables
- Table references in `FROM` can be common table expressions (from the `WITH` clause)

**INSERT statement:**

- `INTO` (Although, it's optional in Teradata)
- `INSERT` or `INS` (Teradata supports `INS` as an alias for `INSERT`)

**UPDATE statement:**

- `UPDATE` or `UPD` ( Teradata supports `UPD` as an alias for `UPDATE`)

**DELETE statement:**

- `FROM` (but the keyword is optional)
- `DELETE` or `DEL` (Teradata supports `DEL` as an alias for `DELETE`)

**MERGE statement:**

- `INTO` (Optional)
- `MERGE`
- `USING`

**DDL statements:**

Don't forget these:

- `TRUNCATE` (`TABLE`)
- `CREATE TABLE`
- `CREATE VIEW`
- `ALTER TABLE`
- `ALTER VIEW`
- `DROP TABLE`
- `DROP VIEW`
- `COMMENT ON TABLE`
- `COMMENT ON VIEW`
- `CREATE INDEX` (`ON` clause)
- `GRANT` (`ON` or `ON TABLE` clause)
- `REVOKE` (`FROM` or `FROM TABLE` clause)

#### Using an existing parser to script this:

If using Java is an option, then you could use [jOOQ's parser](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/sql-parser/sql-parser-api/), run all scripts through it, re-generate the SQL and plug in a [`VisitListener`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/VisitListener.html) to collect all tables. Something like this:

```java
DSLContext ctx = DSL.using(SQLDialect.TERADATA);
ctx.configuration().set(new DefaultVisitListener() {
    @Override
    public void visitStart(VisitContext ctx) {
        if (ctx.queryPart() instanceof Table)
            System.out.println(ctx.queryPart());
    }
});

// The toString() call will trigger a re-generation which passes through the VisitListener
ctx.parser().parse(allSQL).toString();
```

While jOOQ requires a commercial license for `TERADATA`, you might be able to use the free Open Source Edition for this particular task, as the Open Source Edition's parser supports almost all syntax.

Disclaimer: I work for the company behind jOOQ.

Comment: thanks! To my luck I am not trying to interpret the SQL, just fish the tablenames out. So, JOIN will still work, any subqueries will eventually hold a FROM tablename. Also I have grepped all the code for INS \${   or DEL  ... or DELETE ..... without FROM / without INTO. doesnt occur - it is very much standardized. So, for my case, this has confirmed I am complete! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could use built-in mechanism [`SHOW (QUALIFIED)`](https://docs.teradata.com/reader/scPHvjfglIlB8F70YliLAw/BUqdx8bdz7IBWVndYZrSGg):

> Use the QUALIFIED option to produce a report that resolves the ambiguous dependencies.

```
SHOW QUALIFIED SELECT * FROM view_name;
```

This way you will get report with view dependencies. Then you could strip the table names based on that report.

Comment: thanks! do you happen to know how i can get that out of teradata using an ETL tool or stored procedure? Because "SHOW" commands are not supported i am afraid..